# Adding breakpoints on the x-Axis of Histogram MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, histogram

```
OT = [124 124 124 125 125 125 126 249 249 250 250 250 312 312 312 438]
MYBINS = min (OT) : max(OT);
hist (OT,MYBINS);
```

I want to plot the histogram of `OT` and I set my bins from `min(OT)` to `max (OT)`. since the element are far from each other my histogram bars are very small.

I was just wondering how I can modify the x-Axis so it would for example only show the values of the OT next to each other such as `124,125,126,249,250,312,438` and have the corresponding bars on top of them instead of spanning the entire x-Axis.

UPDATE: with the following code I can get the bars above the exact values with the value written underneath, I was just wondering how I can add breaks between far values on the x-Axis?

```
OTU = unique (OT);
OTUS = sort (OTU);
MYBINS = (OTUS);
hist (OT,MYBINS);
```

This is how it looks normally but I would like to have the bars next to each other with the corresponding values below them so the bars would be larger and easier to see

[image: FEmpT.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just get the data from the `hist` function you can plot it in other, more flexible, ways. Is this more like what you want?

```
OT = [124 124 124 125 125 125 126 249 249 250 250 250 312 312 312 438]
binVals = unique(OT);
histVals = hist(OT, binVals);
bar(1:length(histVals), histVals);
set(gca,'XTickLabel', mat2cell(binVals));
```

Comment: Thanks works great I just have a small problem with it. so OT is one array but if I want to have hist of multiple arrays next to each other, I used:
OT = [124 124 124 125 125 125 126 249 249 250 250 250 312 312 312 438];
OT1 = [124 124 124 124 124 124 125 125 125 125 125 126 126 126 126 249 249 250 250 250 312 438 438 438];

binVals = unique(OT);
histVals = hist(OT, binVals);
histVals1 = hist(OT1, binVals);
bar(1:length(histVals),[histVals;histVals1]');
set(gca,'XTickLabel', mat2cell(binVals));

and this works as long as OT and OT1 both contain at least one of the elements of each other

Comment: If i remove 250 from OT1 it won't work anymore and that is the case. I have 2 different arrays and usually they contain all the points but some are missing 1 or 2 points and this will give me "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent" error.

Comment: For some reason my version of MATLAB does not give my that error. You may need `binVals` to include the values from both arrays (`binVals = unique([OT, OT1]);`)

Comment: Your code was awesome, I was making a stupid mistake!! Thanks a lot :)